# Python - remove first column of 0 in dataframe read from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv and the dataframe contains an index of 0's at the beginning.

```
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This removed the actual second column. The first is some kind of index it seems, but just with 0's

Comment: Suggestion: Including the output of your `df.head()` may be useful.

Comment: Intimes of reading set index=false

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like your all-zeros Index, then you may [`reset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) it:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

(note: a `DataFrame` *must* have an Index...)